# How to access a WPF control from the rest of c# application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controls, code-behind

I have a simple WPF window, and it has an image control. I had set the `x:Name="MyImage"` attribute for the image control, and I am able to access the image from the code-behind file, but *how can I access it from the rest of my C# application?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you don't access it from the rest of your application.

WPF is designed to help you keep UI and application logic separate. The former goes in the XAML and .cs "view" files and the latter goes in the .cs "view model" or "model" files (depending on your architecture.

What you can do is bind the UI to a property of the view model. This means that you can set the property to what ever value you like and the view reflects that value to the user. In this scenario you don't set the value in the UI directly but just tell the UI to look at *this* property in the view model to display in *this* way.

Wikipedia has an article on the [Model-View-ViewModel architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) which might be a useful starting point.